# Confluent JDBC connect with Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Can we use Confluent Kafka JDBC connect in Apache Kafka Cluster ?

I am trying to use Confluent JDBC connect to install and configure it on apache kafka cluster for source properties connecting to mssql database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. The JDBC source and sink connector from Confluent is just a plugin for the Kafka Connect framework.

You can find out more here:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector
- http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect